# ReST Webservices: How to accept a list of parameter

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have rest method which should accept a list of objects.
I tried this:

```
@GET     
@Path("/getList")     
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public response getList(@BeanParam List<MyObjects> myobjectsList) {          
//Iterate over the list and return        
return Response.ok(outputList).build();     
}
```

And lets say MyObjects has one attribute:

```
public class MyObjects {
   @QueryParam       
   private String name;

   public String getName() {    
       return name;    
   }
}
```

So when make a rest call: localhost/restservice/getList?name=A&name=B
I get the following exception:

```
Message:A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in java.util.List class.
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=java.util.List
    contracts={java.util.List}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=349
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1585683969
    reified=false)
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in java.util.List class.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:182)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:723)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:678)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:416)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2029)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
//more stack trace
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=java.util.List
    contracts={java.util.List}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=349
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1585683969
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:689)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:416)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2029)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
```

How do I write a ReST method which accepts a list of MyObjects ?

Where am I going wrong with this ?

Comment: well, 1- you are sending params as `Query Params` AFAIK this can only be read by `@QueryParam`, 2- i think if you want to use `@BeanParam` or `@FormParam` ... your method `getList()` should be annotated with `@POST` not `@GET` and then you can send the data in the request's body. **GET** has no body it only sends data via Query Params.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify a query param on the method as a list:

```
@GET     
@Path("/getList")     
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public Response getList(@QueryParam("name") List<String> nameList) {          
    //Iterate over the list and return        
    return Response.ok(nameList).build();     
}
```

The problem is probably due to the use of `QueryParam` in the bean and `BeanParam` on the method. If you wanted to pass a bunch of objects as query params (which seems like a bad idea) you'd have to set them up to be created from the `String`-only representation that query params are.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I am actually new to this. So wan't sure about which annotation to use where. Could you suggest me the best practice to pass a list of objects ?

Comment: No problem, as @Yazan mentioned in his answer, it sounds like you want to send a bunch of data to the server rather than use some query params on a `GET` request, so in this case you should probably use a `POST` or `PUT` method (as `GET` is effectively for retrieving data only). With Jersey you can then just write the Java method to take your object/class type as an argument without any annotations, and use Jackson to convert it from JSON (or similar) sent in the body of the `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of matrix parameters, represented by the [`@MatrixParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html) annotation, as following:

```java
@GET
@Path("/foo")  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public Response someMethod(@MatrixParam("name") List<String> name,
                           @MatrixParam("age") List<Integer> age) {
    ...
}
```

Using this approach, your URL will be like:

```
GET /foo;name=John;age=30;name=Jane;age=20
```

Comment: Hi Cassio, Thanks for the reply. Ross has also mentioned a similar approach. However I fail to understand one thing. MyObjects class has two attributes, lets say name and age.

`@GET
@Path("/getList")  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public Response myMethod(@QueryParam(value = "item") List<MyObjects> item) {
    ...
}`


Then how would the URL look like ?

Comment: @RahulDevMishra Have a look at my updated answer. However, I haven't tried this solution myself.